# Heuristic argument for scaling law of propagator for a gapless particle

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, propagator

Currently reading [Emergent Gravity of Fractons: Mach's Principle Revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07613). The case of interaction between massive particles (fractons) through the exchange of gapped and gapless dipoles are considered. As I understand it, the propagator of the gapless case is not explicitly computed due to self interaction of the dipoles being of similar amplitude to fracton to fracton propagation. And because the background electric field tensor also becomes important.

I do not understand the heuristic argument done in the following 2 images to get the spatial scaling law of the propagator. (see pages 9 and 10 of the paper)

[image: First screenshot of relevant text, see section III C 2)]

[image: Second screenshot of relevant text]

Here is how I understand the argument, and what points I do not get:
-1) branched pathways follow electric field lines. Why?
-Hopping element can thus just be found by counting field lines.
-This field line counting is equivalent to the average E field felt by a fraction due to the other one.
-The electric field has power law. This is explained in another paper.
-Thus hopping term has power law. It is not clear to me why only considering the electric field will give us the right scaling law.